# How to set up recurring contributions on Webform using Stripe

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm, 4.7, stripe

I'm a little confused from other questions here as to whether setting up recurring contributions on a webform using Stripe works.  They work just fine using a regular contribution page. But using a webform that points to the same contribution page the payment goes through as a one-off, even though the 'Frequency of installments' is set to 'month'. If I add either of the other 2 fields 'Number of installments' and 'Interval of installments' fields to the webform I get the message 'Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: total_amount'.  So - recurring contributions can be set up through Stripe, but does/should this work in a webform? If so, any clues as to how you get this to work?

Comment: I would need to look into this to be sure, but webform_civicrm does not use most of the parameters from the contribution page - it's only really used to get the payment processor.  So I suspect that you can't currently do a recurring contribution via the webform integration.  @colemanw would be able to confirm

Comment: Yes you can do recurring contributions via webform_civicrm module [as described in the answer below] - however - Stripe is very different from most payment processors - so I'm wondering whether that works;

Answer (score 1):

As webform_civicrm only uses the contribution page to get the basic details (ie. payment processor) you'd need to configure the rest using the webform_civicrm integration itself.

On the "Contributions" section you have the following options:
[image: Image of "Recurring contribution" section]

I think you will need to enable these, and also configure a "total amount" by activating the "contribution amount" parameter:
[image: contribution amount field]

You can configure all those fields as "hidden" via the webform config once you have enabled them so they are not shown to the user.

Comment: Thanks but didn't work - exactly the same error message as before.  I guess a webform with Stripe just doesn't support recurring payments, which is a shame.